# Diameter of a sphere in the regime of general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems

Lets start naive: empty space, define the origin somewhere, start putting mirrors in a distance of $r$ in many directions so that they roughly sample the surface of a ball of radius $r$.

Someone outside the sphere may measure the radius by sending a light beam through it to an opposite mirror and back to measure the time $t_r$ with their clock, multiply by the speed of light $c$ and to get $4r$. If it were possibly to send light around the circumference along mirrors, the outcome for the circumference would be $2\pi r$.

Now put some mass/energy into the spherical area of space which does not interact with light other than gravitationally. Lets say it is homogeneously distributed.

Someone sitting at the origin having a clock and taking measurements of the radius would measure ... what? I assume $r$ would be the outcome.

Someone using a clock far outside the sphere so that it is not influenced by the mass/energy inside the sphere would measure the radius $r_{out}$ as ... what? I assume according to the outside clock, light takes longer between the mirrors, so we have radius $r_{out} > r$. And similarly for the circumference.

Are these assumptions correct? How can we compute $r_{out}$ for some energy distribution inside the sphere?

Comment: This is a thing that is very commonly done in introductory GR. The radius that appears in Schwarzchild is the radius that if you go around a great circle, you would measure the circumference to be. If you want the radius that passes through the singularity, or through the smooth transition from Schwarzchild to "interior of almost-constant-density star" solution (which then does not have a singularity, everything is well-defined), then you have to use the metric, and it integrates to a different result. You should learn it normally and get this result yourself.